# powershell cloudberry snap in - Select cloud folder - throws 400 bad request error

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3, cloudberry

I am trying to auto sync between amazon s3 bucket and a local folder.

But when i run the command :

```
$source = $s3 | Select-CloudFolder -path TestAutoSync/backup
```

I am getting the below error :

```
Select-CloudFolder : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:1 char:35
+ $source = $s3 | Select-CloudFolder <<<<  -path TestAutoSync/backup
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Select-CloudFolder], BadRequestException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :   CloudBerryLab.Base.Exceptions.BadRequestException,CloudBerryLab.Explorer.PSSnapIn.Comman
 ds.SelectCloudFolder
```

The bucket "TestAutoSync" does exist in my s3 account, and i have cross verified the "key" and "secret". They work perfectly fine when connecting through cloud-berry ui interface.

Below is the complete code executed till the above statement

```
Add-PSSnapin CloudBerryLab.Explorer.PSSnapIn
Set-CloudOption -ProxyAddress xxxx -ProxyPort xxxx
$key = "xxxx"
$secret = "xxxx"
$s3 = Get-CloudS3Connection -Key $key -Secret $secret
$source = $s3 | Select-CloudFolder -path TestAutoSync/backup
```

Please provide your opinions if you have worked around such scenarios earlier.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the TestAutoSync/backup in quotes and does the Select-CloudFolder cmdlet support input from the pipeline?

Comment: What is your CloudBerry Explorer version?

Comment: @Evgeny I am using Cloudberry Freeware 4.7

Comment: @Persistent13 , yes i have tried enclosing using quotes around TestAutoSync/backup and as per the examples i have seen so far, yes,  the Select-CloudFolder cmdlet support input from the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here you go

Get-CloudS3Connection should contain host/path request style setting, that should help you!

Please do the following. Before your line "Get-CloudS3Connection" inject this:

```
set-cloudoption -PathStyle Path
```

So your full code should be something like the below

```
Add-PSSnapin CloudBerryLab.Explorer.PSSnapIn
Set-CloudOption -ProxyAddress xxxx -ProxyPort xxxx -PathStyle Path
$key = "xxxx"
$secret = "xxxx"
$s3 = Get-CloudS3Connection -Key $key -Secret $secret
$source = $s3 | Select-CloudFolder -path TestAutoSync/backup
```

Comment: thanks @Evgeny, but adding -PathStyle did not change anything. I still get the same error...

Comment: Hey Pirate, there is new version of Explorer, you should be fine to have your script up and running!